# Enumerating homologies of disjoint paths

Tags: planar-graphs, algebraic-topology, disjoint-paths, spanning-tree

I am reading this recent [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00185) by Schrijver, in particular, section 4.2: Enumerating homologies of disjoint paths.

I did not understand how do they re-route the paths through a spanning tree and obtain the walks with the mentioned properties, so I decided to work out an example. This is what I have:

[image]

A planar graph with two pairs of terminals and want to find vertex disjoint paths between them (that is $F=\{\{1,2\}\}$). I have also marked a spanning tree $T$ (purple highlighted edges) and numbered the edges $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$ not in the tree such that if $Q_{e_j}$ is longer than $Q_{e_i}$ then $j > i$.
(I haven't marked the direction of the edges because we are considering undirected walks)

[image]

Now I have marked two disjoint paths between the terminals. And according to the algorithm next I am supposed to eliminate $e_2$ from $P_2$ and then $e_4$ from $P_1$.

[image]

But notice that the two walks now cross each other at the top-middle vertex, but the algorithm claimed that the walks obtained will be non-crossing.

Can someone please point out my mistake. Any help would be really appreciated.

---

Even in this 1994 [paper](https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/2257/2257D.pdf), they described a way to enumerate homologies but this method, as it is described, seems more difficult for me to understand.

---

**Edit:** Following is the only way, I was able to find, to re-route those paths through the tree, but as far as I understand, this is not what the paper describes.

[image]